# yowsup program in python not always running on raspian boot

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

finally got Yowsup working on my Pi and it works fantastic. The problem I´m facing now is the following:

I run a command line to get Yowsup working: 
sudo python /home/pi/yowsup/run.py

So I put this same line inside rc.local so that the program starts when raspian boots. The problem is that this solution seems to work randomly and I cant figure out the reason.

I also added the following line to crontab:
@reboot sudo python /home/pi/yowsup/run.py

Still, sometimes it starts and sometimes it does not.

Any ideas? The problem gets specially annoying when booting my Pi headless, because I have to log in another machine to connect to my Pi and run the program remotely.